# JavaScript - Incrementing a value attribute

Tags: javascript, forms, html-table, increment

I have a problem that I can't get my head around (pretty new to JavaScript). Need to know how to increment variables in HTML with an document.createElement event (if that's the right terminology).

I need to increment the 'value' attribute every time the "Add Row" button is clicked and vise versa for the "Delete Row" button.

So far I have:

#### HTML

```
<div id='ctrl_container'>

    <form action='$thisuri' method='post' id='spa' name='date2'>

    <input type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />
    <input type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable')" />

<table id="dataTable"  border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' > 

    <tr>
        <th> Select </th>
        <th> ID </th>
        <th> Question </th>
    </tr>

    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td> <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" /> </td>
        <td> 1<input type="hidden" name="Q[]" value="1" /> </td>
        <td> <input type="text" name="txtbox[]" /> </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>

</table>
    <input type='Submit' value='Submit Planned Audit' name='send'>
    </form>
</div>
```

#### JavaScript

```
function addRow(tableID) {

        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

        var rowCount = document.getElementById(tableID).getElementsByTagName('tbody')
        [1].getElementsByTagName('tr').length;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount +1);

        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var element1 = document.createElement("input");
        element1.type = "hidden";
        element1.name = "Q[]";
        element1.value = rowCount +1;
        cell2.appendChild(element1);
        cell2.innerHTML = rowCount +1;
}

function deleteRow(tableID) {
        try {
        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;

        for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
            var row = table.rows[i];
            var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
            if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
                table.deleteRow(i);
                rowCount--;
                i--;
            }


        }
        }catch(e) {
            alert(e);
        }
}
```

Can someone give me some pointers?

Comment: Does the rest of your code work? Could you maybe provide a jsFiddle. Please explain why you need to increment, and where you want to show the number of rows?

Comment: Try to alert(rowcount) and see what's happening with it

Comment: @NickN. http://jsfiddle.net/2wpaL/1/ I need to increment the value attribute in the hidden input type. I did alert(rowCount) but got nothing. ill try again. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle, the fiddle shows me, that what you say, could not be what you want to do. Since when we add 2 rows, and then delete the second. The next row added will be also called 3. Which will result in 2 rows having the ID=3. Are you sure this is the right question to ask?

Comment: Yeah i know, that's why i need to de-increment as well, i thought i could fix both problems in one hit, maybe a rethink?

Comment: Well it is deincrementing, but not to the existing rows. By the way is it just to indicate the row number or is it an actual Id for later use?

Comment: It used to be to just indicated a row number. The bigger picture is to use it with php and generate a dynamic query to create a table in a database and subsequently a checklist, i wanted to move away from static checklists you see.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29916/discussion-between-nick-n-and-edward)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pDxnb/1/

It will definitely give you some pointers, since the row is actually being added visibly now. (The rowcount is not the problem here I guess)

The problem was and still is, is that you are adding empty cells as a row. I have added cell2 to the table and we can see things are happening.

```
var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
cell2.appendChild(element1);
cell2.innerHTML = rowCount +1;
```

also what I did to debug is:

```
    alert(rowCount);
```

You should be able to figure the rest out for yourself. If you need anymore help please comment below.

**TIP:**

Maybe it would be better to get your highest ID incremented everytime adding a row, and don't worry about the deletion. This way you can never have the same ID's

Answer (score 1):

If you want to increment by name :

```
var hiddenInputs = document.getElementsByName("Q[]");
```

EDIT :

```
for (var i = 0; i <= hiddenInputs.length; i++) {
    hiddenInputs[i].value = i + 1;
}
```

Decrement has the same logic. Now, value of the hiddenInput(DOM element) consist your row count

Comment: Ill give this a go and see where it leads. Cheers Mustafa!

Comment: as the input element is cloned to each row so it increments the first hidden field it finds... How can i get around that? Will incrementing hiddenInput[0].value work?

Comment: My edit solves whole the problem i think. It puts all numbers starting from zero.

Comment: Can you send over a fiddle??

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9YCeu/ Delete one of rows and run again. You will see that numbers are correctly given. On every addition or deletion this code must run as far as I understand from your question

Comment: It works in the fiddle you sent but when i put it in my code it has no affect, is this right? - http://jsfiddle.net/9YCeu/1/

Comment: This code edits only the 'value' attribute, not the HTML displaying. don'T edit value attribute, just set the innerHTML.